# How can I structure the opening hours of some place in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, schema

I need to design a way for my database to be able to store different opening hours of a place, let's say a bar or a restaurant. These opening hours can be different from day to day, and they need to work with hours such as 9:30 or 8:15, not only integers.

This is what I came up with:

```
opening_hours: {
        normal_days: {
            mon: {
                start: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
                end: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
            },
            tue: {
                start: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
                end: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
            },
            wed: {
                start: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
                end: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
            },
            thu: {
                start: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
                end: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
            },
            fri: {
                start: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
                end: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
            },
            sat: {
                start: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
                end: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
            },
            sun: {
                start: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
                end: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
            },
        },
        special_days: {
            date: Date,
            name: String,
            start: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
            end: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 23 },
            is_closed: Boolean,
        },
    },
```

I can't find a better way of doing it, unfortunately. What do you think would be an optimal schema for that problem?

Answer (score 6):

I once had the same issue, and this is how I implemented:

```
opening_hours: [{
 day: {type Date}, //mon - sun
 periods: [{
   start: {type Date},
   end: {type Date}
   }]
 }]
```

The reason why `periods` is an array is that you could have like

```
[
 { 
   start: 9h00,
   end: 11h00
 },
 { 
   start: 13h00,
   end: 18h00
 }
]
```

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: Hi, I am trying to implement this but not sure how to input the day Mon-Sunday

Answer (score 0):

I don't see too many things wrong with this (except that it doesnt include 23:00-24:00), that being said:

If I were designing this, I wouldnt use abbreviations for the property names. Id use full "thursday" for example, and then in the object itself, have something like `shorthand : 'THU'`. I would also avoid using hours as 0-23 everywhere. Probably something like

```
{ 
...
shorthand: "THU"
startHours: 0-23,
endHours: 0-23,
startMinutes: 0-59,
endMinutes: 0-59,
startInMilliseconds: 0 - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 - 1,
endInMilliseconds: 0 - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 - 1
}
```

This would allow you to work across timezones and things like that, since you can just manipulate unix epoch time easily. And breaking your time into hours and minutes would allow you to get to 23:59, plus formatting would just be `${thursday.startHours}:${thursday.startMinutes}` Rather than some weird math to convert from 23.75 -> 23:45.

Of course this all depends on the actual use case for your data.

Comment: Storing the unix epoch time is a good idea. I also thought about storing the opening hours as a string that would consist of 4 digits (validated by a regex or something like that) so we would have `start: 0800, end: 1900` for instance, and then manipulate it using moment.js. Would that work too?

Comment: @Anthony timeAsString would actually be nice too. I was thinking about that for display purposes, but you might have to jump through some hoops every time you update the start and end times. But I imagine you have an updateTime() function that will take hours and minutes and do all that magic for you so I guess its not a big deal. Which in that case, would definitely save some time to store as string for display purposes. Not sure if I like the audio of using it for the actual time manipulation in moment.js though, Id rather keep math with numbers, and display with strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
opening_hours: {
    normal_days: {
        monday: {
            start: { type: Date, default: new Date().setHours(8, 0, 0, 0) },
            end: { type: Date, default: new Date().setHours(4, 30, 0, 0) },
        },
        tuesday: {
            start: { type: Date, },
            end: { type: Date, },
        },
    }
}
```

When you query the database you can get the hour or minute components separately. Date objects store the date, time, and timezone. Most programming languages have functions to parse the hour, minute, and timezone from a Date object. MongoDB has $hour, $minute, and $dayOfWeek operators among others.

[MongoDB Date Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/#example)

[Javascript Get Date Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)